# Can every node of a link/cut tree be accessed in $O(n)$ time?

Tags: time-complexity, splay-trees

Per the Sequential Access Theorem we can access every node of a splay tree in $O(n)$ time, when accessing the nodes in a specific order.

Given a link/cut tree, is it possible to access all of its nodes faster than the naive $O(n \log n)$ amortized time in the worst-case?